# Blazor WebAssembly blocks WebApi AllowAnonymous

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I have created an Blazor WebAssembly project and want to provide a WebAPI with one public available function.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class SystemEvalApiController : ControllerBase
{
    public SystemEvalApiController(AppDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {...}

    [Route("LatestEvals")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult LatestEvals()
```

that is my Api controller and I should be able to call it with:

```
SystemEvalPublicViewModel = await Http
                .GetFromJsonAsync<SystemEvalPublicViewModel>(
                    HttpService.BuildUrl("api/SystemEvalApi/LatestEvals"));
```

When i am not logged into any account. But instead I get this error:

```
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.JPB.BorannRemapping.ServerAPI.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request GET https://localhost:44330/api/SystemEvalApi/LatestEvals
blazor.webassembly.js:1 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed.
```

It looks like the "DefaultAuthorizationService" does not recognize the Anonymous attribute but I cannot find the point where it fails directly.

How do I declare an WebAPI function to be accessable from the HttpClient without Login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server 3.2.0.-rc1.20223.4

Edit:
Here is the declaration for ClientServices:

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("JPB.BorannRemapping.ServerAPI", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
    })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

// Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("JPB.BorannRemapping.ServerAPI"));
builder.Services.AddTransient(e => new HttpService(e.GetService<HttpClient>()));
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you register your services and how your inject them ?
The Blazor app doesn't know how your protect your api, it cannot guess there 's a method allowing anonymous user. It's like a service you don't write for the app.

Comment: i added the program.cs contents. I inject the HttpClient (or HttpService, its just a wrapper with common used methods) by the normal @inject syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So each time you acquire an `HttpClient` it use the `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` which try to authentify the request. But it this case your request should not be authentified, so you can make something like :

**Registration**

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("JPB.BorannRemapping.ServerAPI.Anonymous", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
    });
```

**Usage**

```cs
@inject IHttpClientFactory _factory

@code {
...
     var httpClient = _factory.CreateClient("JPB.BorannRemapping.ServerAPI.Anonymous");
     var httpService = new HttpService(httpClient);
     SystemEvalPublicViewModel = await httpClient
                .GetFromJsonAsync<SystemEvalPublicViewModel>(
                    httpService.BuildUrl("api/SystemEvalApi/LatestEvals"));
}
```

Comment: This was a big help to me a year and a half later, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer from @agua from mars.

**Registration in Program.cs**

You could add 2 named HttpClient to the services collection (the first for authenticated calls the second for anonymous):

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("YourProject.ServerAPI", 
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("YourProject.ServerAPI.Anonymous", 
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));

// Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("YourProject.ServerAPI"));
//Register a new service for getting an Anonymous HttpClient
builder.Services.AddScoped<IHttpAnonymousClientFactory, HttpAnonymousClientFactory>();
```

**Add new Interface and Implementation for Dependency Injection:**

```
    public interface IHttpAnonymousClientFactory
    {
        HttpClient HttpClient { get; }
    }

    public class HttpAnonymousClientFactory : IHttpAnonymousClientFactory
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

        public HttpAnonymousClientFactory(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        public HttpClient HttpClient => httpClientFactory.CreateClient("YourProject.ServerAPI.Anonymous");
    }
```

**Usage in Razor Component (for Anonymous HttpClient)**

```
        [Inject]
        private IHttpAnonymousClientFactory httpAnonymousClientFactory { get; set; }

        private MyViewModel myModel;

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            myModel = await httpAnonymousClientFactory.HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<MyViewModel>($"api/mycontroller/myendpoint");
        }
```

**Usage in Razor Component (for Authenticated HttpClient)**

```
        [Inject]
        private HttpClient httpClient { get; set; }

        private MyOtherViewModel myModel;

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            myModel = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<MyOtherViewModel>($"api/mycontroller/mysecureendpoint");
        }
```